# Print repetition in Swift while statement

Tags: swift, api, while-loop, alamofire, swift5

In my while statement, I cannot understand why my output is printed twice ?
I would like to print i only one time, where is my error ?

```swift
func fetch2(){
    var i: Int = 0
    while i <= (self.returned-1) {
        let itemLookUp = "https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemLookup?appid=\(self.appId)&itemcode=\(self.arrayCodeProduct[i])&responsegroup=large"
        print(i)            
        i = i+1 
    }
}
```

Here is the output that I obtain :

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `fetch2` called twice?

Comment: fetch2() is called once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `fetch2()` is called twice.

Add a `print(#function)` before you `var i` and check that `fetch2()` is not called several times.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, I have forgot a fetch2() call somewhere, thank you !

Comment: Great, don't hesitate to accept the answer!